# Samsung Galaxy A12 not tethering with Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, samsung, tethering

I bought a new Samsung Galaxy A12, and I'm trying to tether my laptop which is running Ubuntu 20.04. The connection is detected on the laptop, but it keeps saying connecting but does not connect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having the same issue while `usb-tethering` from my galaxy a12 @ `kubuntu 22.04` (pc and laptop)
`netstat -i` shows some `rx-errors` on every  phone's response to dhclient's request (here is the basic problem?)

Tempor way is to use adb port forwarding + ssh

ex. (**phone**, termux - no root): 
`$ sshd -p 6666`

acquire termux-wakelock to not put sshd to sleep

then, (**pc**, having the phone connected via usb): 
`$ adb forward tcp:6666 tcp:6666`
`$ ssh -D 8887 u0_a266@127.0.0.1 -p 6666`

**before** you may to setup pass (termux): 
`$ passwd`

use `whoami` to find out your uname on termux (ex: u0_a266)

**also**, you should have been installed (termux):

```
apt update -y && apt upgrade -y
apt install openssh
```

and `adb` (pc)

**then** setup `socks5://127.0.0.1:8887` proxy for apt, chrome, firefox, etc on your pc/laptop

**UPD**: still not working