# Unable to tether Samsung A12

Tags: proxy, samsung, tethering

I found [this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/1408489/1564771) and followed it up to the proxy, but I can't get the proxy working. I would ideally want my entire system to use the proxy and have it configured automatically when I enable tethering.